# Blender as python module, 'Context' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, scripting

I understand that running blender without a GUI does not provide `bpy.context` for the 3d View. Can anyone help me with a work around. This results in a 'Context' object has no attribute 'object' error.

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for object in scene.objects:
        if bpy.context.mode == 'OBJECT':
            if object.name != 'Lamp':
                if object.name != 'Camera':
                    print("deleting " + object.name)
                    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
                    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add({'scene': scene, 'active_object': object})
                    print(bpy.context.object)
```

Comment: The script runs fine GUI-less. Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#hasattr) or [catch and handle the exceptions](http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought I needed to link the object to the scene and make it active.

Comment: @Aldrik it is not so immediately clear so I don't think it should be closed as such. Can you form your comment into an answer? Python related questions are allowed to an extent if kept simple and in relation to Blender somewhat.

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. I am trying to understand blender python interface. How would I make python from terminal run                          import bpy                             bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()                      without causing RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Comment: Note: the example loops over data its deleting, since it calls `bpy.ops.object.delete` it could be deleting many objects at once, suggest you use `scene.objects.remove(obj)` so you have better control, and make a copy of the objects list before looping over it. eg, `for ob in scene.objects[:]:   ....`

Answer (score 4):

Variables are not always available in the context, typically you can access them directly, in the case of the active object you can access it from 
`scene.objects.active` (most collections that have an active member work this way).

Comment: Thank you for providing a response which explains a tib bit of the python blender interface. I wish I could hire you to teach me a good foundation.